# Cannot deploy an application to Glassfish 4.1 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have Glassfish 4.1 and Eclipse Luna installed on Ubuntu. When I tried to run a simple web application (jsp + servlet + java bean) I`ve received the following error:

`Publishing to Glassfish 4 at localhost[domain1].. has encountered a
 problem. 
 cannot Deploy mvcprj1  deploy is failing=Application with
 name [mvcprj1] is not deployed`

Nothing is appearing neither in the glassfish server log or in the eclipse console.

Comment: Check eclipse's log itself (under the workspace, .metadata, .log). You might find the cause is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786155/glassfish-4-1-deploy-is-failing-on-eclipse-luna-with-jdk-8/28084272#28084272

Comment: Got the same on Windows 7: fresh unpacked GlassFish 4.1 > new EAR and EJB projects, one simple SBean with `public String hello()` > run on server > same error, no log... I could reproduce it multiple times whilst creating new projects... Then somehow I tried to enable "Use JAR archives for deployment" - then it worked! Since then I can no more reproduce the error, even while re-installing the whole server!? I doubt that this was really the solution, but perhaps somebody could confirm that? Perhaps it was a problem of Eclipse?

Answer (score 61):

I had same deployment issue (eclipse Lune/Glassfish 4.1) and it was resolved thanks to Marvin's feedback.

You can find the "Use JAR archives for deployment" by: 
right click on glassfish from eclipse server tab. Then, select **Monitoring**  >**Properties** > **Glassfish** in new windows > **Use JAR archives for deployment**.

Then, the miracle occurs...

Comment: After doing this, you can also rightclick on the server and  select "Clean" and afterwards uncheck the box again. After a redeploy everything will work as before.

Comment: This fixed the problem with Eclipse Neon too. Thanks

Comment: In 2019 eclipse  2019-09 R (4.13.0) and Glassfish is still the same. Thank you very much and thanks to @jowey - the clean trick works also!

Answer (score 12):

Try the following steps:

1. right click on **glassfish** server
2. click on **properties**
3. then you will get 3 options(general,glassfish,monitoring) at the left side of that box.
4. click on glassfish
5. click that checkbox "Use JAR archives for depolyment". Previously it was unchecked. That's why I was getting issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the Glassfish server instance in eclipse and recreated it to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that occurs, when one has not closed the "Browser Page" in Eclipse, after he had tried out the same application previous time. After closing all open "Browser Pages" of this application in Eclipse, the deployment is possible again.